# How to use an ssh Api Key in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ssh, postman

I wanted to know if you can help me with this problem, I am currently using Newman to load a collection of test cases that I made in Postman, I am trying to run a JOB in Jenkins, when I run the command:

```
newman run collection.json -e sendoment.json
```

It works, the collection runs in Jenkins but it shows me this error:

```
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8095
```

I know that I have to pass the ssh code to it so that it recognizes the port and gives me access, but I don't know what commands to use to send it.

I currently have an id_rsa.pub that I use to perform this action locally.

My question is, how can I send this file or how can I make sure the ports will be there? I do not have privileges to enter the Managment, so I cannot add the variable as a plugin, I have seen this in other blogs either here or in Postman.

[image]

It is just a collection in json format with various calls to various EndPoints, where the states they have are validated.

Comment: We need more details like what is the code in collection.json, you may probably need to call the jenkins url providing the job token like: http://jenkins_URL:8095/job?MyJobName&token=TOKENyousetupInTheJob something like that.

Comment: I just edited the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this action I had to create a method that would allow me to log in to the virtual machine that I have in Jenkins, since, when performing the action, this port is blocked. 2 Cookies are sent to perform the Log In action.